# Can I say, 'Do it thus' instead of 'Do it like this'?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, word-meaning, difference

Are "thus" and "like this" always interchangeable? Thank you in advance.

Comment: They _mean_ the same, but 'thus' sounds very formal and old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1):

The word "*thus*" is now somewhat rare, and is generally used only in very formal writing, or in fixed and fossilized phrases used in specific contexts.  I do see it in mathematical proofs, and in literary critic. where it often means "therefore" and not "in this way" so the words are not always interchangeable. Some examples:

> - Addition is commutative, and thus 2+3 = 3+2.
> - Turin's haste and easy anger leads to disaster, and thus we see the importance of good character in Tolkien's writing.

"Thus" was traditionally used to indicate the direction a helmsman was to follow on a sailing ship. "This way" would not often be used in that context.

In current writing I would avoid "thus" except in contexts where it is still in frequent use.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, although I'm not quite as averse to "thus" as you are; I use it occasionally. I think that your advice to learners is excellent, though, since in many cases it can sound unnatural (as in OP's example sentence).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Oh I use it occasionally myself, I have something of a fondness for both formal and old-fashioned language. In fact I just used it in a [comment here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/331634/can-the-phrase-bobbing-in-the-water-be-used-to-say-a-person-is-struggling/331636?noredirect=1#comment627645_331636). But I believe that I know when it works and when it does not. The above was written as advice to a learner, who may well not know what it will sound odd or wrong.