# Can the phrase "bobbing in the water" be used to say a person is struggling?

Tags: word-usage, usage, phrases, sentence

If I say I can't seem to get ahead or stop "bobbing in the water" does it let the reader know that I am struggling.

Comment: By "struggling" do you mean "trying hard to learn to swim" or "almost drowning".

Comment: flailing in the water

Comment: The simple answer is No.  It's totally different.

Comment: Broadly no; never without extra qualification. 'Bobbing' and 'struggling' are in no way comparable. If you accept that for instance, corks and their like 'bob' does that remove any doubt?

Answer (score 27):

I, personally, would also use "floundering" to imply they were sinking in the water. Bobbing, to me, implies they *could* (but not always) be quite comfortable and in no distress.

Comment: And more than that, people actually use the word "floundering" (when having great difficulty with a particular task). I've never heard anyone say they were "bobbing".

Comment: Yes, bobbing normally implies floating, which implies not drowning.

Comment: "Bobbing" implies a *resistance* to sinking.

Comment: @chepner "Bobbing" implies a passive resistance to sinking through buoyancy. "Floundering" implies making an active effort even if ineffective. For example apples can bob in water. If they flounder someone's been messing with their DNA.

Comment: To me, "bobbing" sounds more like the person *already* drowned and is now just a floating corpse.  I would definitely avoid using this word to refer to a living person, especially one who is actively struggling.

Answer (score 25):

The phrase "*bobbing in the water*" generally refers to a floating object moving up and down as small waves affect it. It is particularly often used for small boats, water fowl such as ducks, and fishing floats on a fishing line. It would not usually suggest a person struggling in the water, or trying to swim but having problems.

I suppose it **could** be used in that way, but it would be confusing unless explained, in which case many would think it odd.

"*Treading water*" refers to a person upright in the water, keeping his or her head above the surface by making motions with the feet and legs. It is often associated with a person who cannot really swim, or can't swim well. It is used metaphorically to mean struggling, barely avoiding disaster.

"*Just keeping one's head above water*" also suggests a person barely avoiding drowning.

### Usage of "Treading water"

Here are some examples found via Google books:

- *Treading Water* by Carrie Wills (ISBN  9781628577846; 2014) (Page 5: “Are we simply treading water? Just looking out for something better?” —Al Lewis, “Treading Water”)
- *Swimming Lessons: Life Lessons from the Pool, from Diving in to Treading Water* By Penelope Niven (ISBN: 9780156027076; 20040 (Page 7: I am not the only person who has had to learn how and when to tread water--to hold on, to wait, to endure--as well as how and when to swim like crazy...)
- *Stoner & Spaz - Book 1* by Ron Koertge (ISBN: 9780763657574; 2011) ("Since I've been pretty much treading water all day, the marquee of the Rialto Theater looks like the prow of a ship coming to save me.)

I think that on looking at these and the many other examples of this phrase, one will see that it is used in a variety of ways, not merely for lack of effort as a comment by Tetsujin  suggests

Comment: I would consider 'treading water' in a metaphorical sense to be 'someone doing the absolute minimum of work' rather than struggling. It implies laziness not lack of ability. Treading water in the physical sense is the least energetic way to stay afloat. [I agree with the rest.]

Comment: @Tetsujin I dont think the expression is used exclusively to imply laziness or minimum work.  It just implies that someone's actions dont give them any actual progress, and just keep them "afloat".

Comment: @Tetsujin I disagree.  To me it's just not getting any progress out of your efforts.  Also, backfloat is the least energetic way to stay afloat, I'd even suggest treading water is probably the single most tiring way to not go under.

Comment: @Tetsujin  "*treading water*" used in a metaphorical sense, is used in several different ways. It can imply stagnation, "running hard just to stay in place". It does not always imply lack of effort or laziness.

Comment: Then we're going to have to agree to disagree. If someone told me someone was treading water in a job, they would be at the bottom of my list for promotion. Maybe this is just another transpondian difference of meaning...

Comment: @Tetsujin You might want to look at the examples I have added to my answer.

Comment: Two are American, one possibly Mexican. I shall still disagree. It in no way means 'struggling'.

Comment: @Tetsujin Not "struggling" so much as "making a futile effort" or "holding on, avoiding disaster but not achieving success". but it can be used in other ways as well. Like many metaphoric expressions, it does not have a single rigid fixed meaning.

Comment: We're still going to have to disagree. No matter what justification you find for your interpretation, I think this is a poor term to use for the OP's issue. 'just keeping one's head above water' should have been your main thrust, though I still prefer 'floundering'.

Comment: ''We're treading water financially'' is a thing I heard a lot growing up (at least in my part of England), meaning we're struggling somewhat or only just making ends meet.

Comment: @Tetsujin it may imply lack of _ability_ but not laziness. Treading water as opposed to swimming implies just staying afloat and alive rather than making progress toward land.

Comment: Treading water when swimming is intentionally used to stop moving and keep your head above water. It's less effort than moving, safer for resting than a backfloat if there are waves that may break over your head, and it's not futile or wasteful, and it certainly isn't struggling. If you're struggling to tread water, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Randy Orrison  All quite true. But the stereotype is that it is a last resort of a swimmer in trouble, even though that is not correct. And thus the **metaphoric** use is for one making effort that avoids disaster, but makes no progress. At least that is a very common metaphoric meaning, it is used in other senses as well.

Comment: Is the question asking for metaphorical usage, or literal? If metaphorical, then yes treading water is appropriate, and I'm not disagreeing with that. I took it to be asking for a literal answer, in which case floundering is much better than treading water.

Comment: To me both "treading water" and "bobbing in the water" imply you're not making any progress, but your position is stable, things aren't desperate, but you're not moving forward. "Treading water" implies you're having to make an effort to stay in the same place, "Bobbing in the water" implies you stay in the same place without significant effort. "Floundering" implies you're struggling to stay afloat.

Comment: David, while this is an excellent and detail essay, the full and complete answer to the question asked is:  "No."  There's a great danger on this learner's site that long answers (which should be answered "No") can misguide the reader.  I may suggest adding a first paragraph, "No." and then a second paragraph "Here's some more info."

Comment: For example, "I suppose it could be used in that way, but it would be confusing" that sentence is absolutely true of ... anything whatsoever, with no limitations.  Can you spell dog as ndogg? I suppose it could be spelled that way, but it would be confusing.  THe very simple answer here is "It can not be used that way."

Comment: @Fattie  I must strongly disagree. If anyone had answered this question with a simple "no" and no further explanation, I would at least have downvoted it.  I would probably have simply deleted it as "not an answer". Unexplained "yes" and "no answers are not acceptable here. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center. Saying "no" and then explaining why not at some length might be a valid answer, but not one I could agree with in this particular case.

Comment: Hi David, I meant "the answer" (platonically, not "An Answer In The SO Database!") to the question is ........ "No".  As I stated (sorry if unclear), your SOAnswer would be perfect if you add the needed preamble: "No. Here's a discussion."

Comment: Further I've realized you may be simply wrong.  "It would not usually suggest a person struggling in the water" is completely wrong.   Only solid/fixed-shape objects can bob.  Such as a boat not under power, or anything like an apple tossed in the water.  the only way a human can bob is if, the human, absolutely perfectly holds still. ("She froze herself in a ball shape in the water and didn't move a muscle, and then she bobbed up and down - the kids laughed to see a human bobbing!")

Comment: @Fattie I see. Yes that would be a reasonable answer, but not one I agree with. I will not be making that change to this answer. Feel free to post a different answer taking that view, if you wish. I generally avoid answers here that give absolute Yes/No answers, even with a full discussion, except in the very clearest of cases. Indeed a point I make over and over is that there are many fewer absolute "rules" in English than many learners suppose that there are.

Comment: Certainly, TBC when someone (say me) says "damn you, this answer should be _ _ _" the implication is "IMO the answer should be _ _ _".  Certainly, the other party (yourself in this case) need not even state "I choose not to make that change!!"  Heh!  Tally ho ..

Answer (score 4):

No, the  expressions that might be appropriate are:

**just treading water**  and  **swimming against the tide**.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-not-make-progress

Answer (score 4):

“Bobbing in the water” means something moves up and down in the water, only caused by the wave movement.

I might be lying on my back, totally relaxed, or I might be treading water, upright with minimal effort to keep my head out of the water. In both cases I’ll be bobbing in the water, and I’m not struggling at all. If I’m struggling, that’s something completely different what you see.

Now it’s possible that I struggled, lost, and drowned. Now I’m bobbing again, but the struggle is over.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean this figuratively, then the closest idiomatic expression would be "trying to keep one's head above water" or "barely keeping one's head above water".

This would mean that you are struggling to get by or get through difficult circumstances.

"Keep one's head above water" means to just get by without doing particularly well, so *trying* to do that, or *barely* doing it, suggests struggling to get by.

Answer (score 0):

The clearest swimming analogy I can think of for struggling is "staying afloat"

"just staying afloat"
"trying hard to stay afloat"
"struggling to stay afloat"
"fighting to stay afloat"

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I hope you like the place and decide to visit often. You might want to read the [Contributor's guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4783/91457). It has a lot of helpful information on how best to ask and answer, questions here on ELL.